# If AppPool is recycled, what will happen to in-progress web service calls

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis

I have a asp.net web app and few actions are performed using WCF.

My question is -

While my WCF method call is in progress, the application pool is reset  due to: 
1) Change in Web.Config
2) Some assembly is deployed in Bin Folder
3) IIS Crash
4) IIS Stops

What will happen to my method call?

Things I have tried:
1) Applied Thread.Sleep of 20 Secs in WCF method
2) While the WCF method is in progress, I changed the assembly in bin folder.
Result - Surprisingly, the Success Callback of WCF method is called and the WCF method is called successfully. 
As per my expectation, it should go to the Failure Callback.

Comment: Well, that's good news isn't it? And [reset != recycled](https://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/10307/understanding-application-pool-recycling-and-how-to-fine-tune-for-use-with-outsys/).

Answer (score 4):

http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/provisioning-and-managing-iis/features-of-the-windows-process-activation-service-was

In the "Recycling" section

> WAS does this by spawning up a new worker process parallel to the old one that is still handling requests. Once the new worker process is up it starts picking up requests from the request queue while the old worker process is instructed by WAS to stop picking up requests. Once the old worker process finishes all executing requests it shuts down. This feature is called "overlapping recycling". It ensures that no requests are lost during a recycle.